# Building Social Network with retweet like functionality

Tags: 7

I'm designing a social network that I'd like to build on Drupal 7. I'd like people to have a Twitter-like feed that they can follow people/orgs and see their own posts and "re-tweets".

I'm currently starting to look at Organic groups, I invision the owner(s) of the group posting content to a group and anyone visiting that group page would see the group's "feed"(a view). However, I'm not sure how to implement the "retweet" feature that allows a piece content to be viewed by a retweeter's set of followers.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [statuses](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module for this. See [this post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1228534) for discussion of retweet functionality with statuses.